# Rendering both drawer and tabbed navigation with react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation in my react native app, and I'm looking to render both the drawer navigation and tab navigation components simultaneously.

At first, I tried to render both in the root app component, but that threw an error that appears in their documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html). I then attempted the solution listed below, which produced the following for me:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  }
});

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Products: {
    screen: ProductsScreen
  },
  TabNav: TabNavigator
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigator />;
  }
}
```

[image]

The tab navigation only shows when I select the TabNav link in the drawer navigation. I want it on every screen. I also don't want the TabNav label to show in the drawer navigation.

Am I missing something in the documentation, or is this the intended functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, move the TabNav to first in the navigator like this

```
TabNav: TabNavigator,
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Products: {
    screen: ProductsScreen
  }
```

or else you change the initialRouteName to "TabNav"

For the Second question,

If you want the TabNavigation to show inside the HomeScreen and ProductsScreen you need to include TabNavigation in both 
or they need to have a parent TabNavigation which contains those. I can add a sample code if you post what the TabNav contains.

And for the Third question,

You can use contentComponent in DrawerNavigator example like this

```
contentComponent: props => (
    <AppDrawerContent {...props} navigation={props.navigation} />
),
```

Edited:
If you want TabNavigator to show on each one. I think you should change the way you Structure your navigator.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return < TabNavigator />;
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Drawer: {
    screen: AppNavigator
  }
});
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Products: {
    screen: ProductsScreen
  }
});
```

or else if you want TabNavigator inside each screen individually then

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  HomeNavigator: {
    screen: HomeScreenNavigator
  },
  Products: {
    screen: ProductsScreen
  }
});

const HomeScreenNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Settings: {
   screen: SettingsScreen
  }
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigator />;
  }
}
```

*Like wise for Products screen also.*

What you have actually done is you included the TabNav as Drawer Screen so it does appear in the Drawer side bar.

Even if this structure doesn't work you need to check on restructuring it. Or you may give a images how you want to show it. May be I could help you with better understanding.

Comment: Your answers worked, but I'm a little confused about the second answer. I need to include the TabNavigation in the HomeScreen and ProductsScreen components?

You said you can post an example if I post what TabNav contains, but the code for that navigator is posted above the Drawer Navigation component

Comment: Edited my Answer

Comment: Sorry about that, you should have it now! :)

Comment: As this show up in google, I want to add this snack , in case anyone want to live working demo using expo snack.expo.io/@cjmling/react-tab-and-drawer